# Set property from outside Angular on Angular component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an Angular component as follows

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-view',
  templateUrl: './data-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-view.component.scss']
})
export class DataViewComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() data = { val: 1 };
  ...
}
```

I would like to set `data` on that component from outside of Angular, so I did

```
const el = document.querySelector('app-data-view');
console.log(el.data);  // -> undefined
el.data = { val: 2 };  // -> nothing happens
```

That didn't work, and nothing happened. The only thing that seems to work is with dispatchEvent and @HostListener. But I was wondering if I'm doing something wrong in my above example?

Comment: You should try with `setAttribute` to pass `data` to your component.

Comment: I think you can only set a string with `setAttribute`, it should be with `properties`

Comment: Why do you want to set the value from outside of Angular?

Comment: I'm writing a web-component library with StencilJS and in one of the components I have **<slot />** which will hold an angular component (or React or Vue). From my web-component I need to pass data to this received (slot) component

Answer (score 1):

### You have to get the component instance not HTML DOM element

To get component instance type in the console:

```
ng.probe(document.querySelector('app-data-view')); // returns Angular Component
```

Read more here: https://juristr.com/blog/2016/02/debugging-angular2-console/

**Unless you write dev tools, you MUST NOT change the state of the angular component in this way.**